# Understanding strings as pointers in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, memory-management, memory-address

I have troubles understanding strings as pointers. Apparently a string is understood as a pointer which points to the first address of the string. So using the "&"-operator I should receive the address of the first character of the string. Here's a small example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char text[101]; 
    int length;
    cout << "Enter a word: ";
    cin >> text;
    length = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        cout << " " << &text[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When entering a word such as "Hello", the output is: "Hello ello llo lo o". Instead I expected to receive the address of each character of "Hello". When I use the cast `long(&text[i])` it works out fine. But I don't understand why. Without the cast, apparently the "&"-operator gives the starting address of the string to be printed. Using a cast it gives the address of every character separately. 
Maybe sb. can explain this to me - I'd be really grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a character array storing a string as for example

```
char text[] = "Hello";
```

then the array is initialized like

```
char text[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

In this statement

```
std::cout << text;
```

there is used `operator <<` overloaded for the type `const char *` and the array `text` is converted implicitly to pointer to its first element.

You could write instead

```
std::cout << &text[0];
```

because in the both statements the expressions `text` and `&text[0]` have type `char *`.

The operator overloaded for the type `const char *` outputs characters starting from the address at the pointer until a zero character is encountered.

So if instead of the statement

```
std::cout << &text[0];
```

you'll write

```
std::cout << &text[1];
```

then the only thing that is changed is the starting address of the string and nothing more. That is in fact you are outputting string that is represented like

```
{ 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }
```

If to write

```
std::cout << &text[2];
```

that is if the pointer in the right side of the expression is moved one position right then it means that you'll deal with the string

```
{ 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }
```

and so on.

That is the `operator <<` overloaded like

```
template<class traits>
basic_ostream<char, traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<char, traits>&,
const char*);
```

just outputs entities pointed to by the second parameter as strings.

If you want to output the value of the pointer itself instead of the string pointed to by the pointer you should use another overloaded `operator <<` declared like

```
basic_ostream<charT, traits>& operator<<(const void* p);
```

Tp invoke it you should write for example

```
std::cout << ( void * )text;
```

or

```
std::cout << ( void * )&text[i];
```

where `i` is some index.

Instead of the C casting you can use C++ casting like

```
std::cout << static_cast<void *>( &text[i] );
```

Comment: This is the only answer who really explain @Luk doubt.
But, apparently, it only matter answer first.

Comment: thx very much! I'm new to programming and I am currently wondering how a type can be `void*`

Comment: @Luk Consider void * as a pointer to a raw memory the actual type of which is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

`&text[i]` is equivalent to `text + i` and that shifts the pointer along the `char[]` array by `i` places using *pointer arithmetic*. The effect is to start the `cout` on the (i)th character, with the overload of `<<` to a `const char*` called. That outputs all characters from the starting point up to the NUL-terminator.

`text[i]` however is a `char` type, and the overload of `<<` to a `char` is called. That outputs a single character.

In C++, if you want a string, then use `std::string` instead. You can still write `cin >> text;` if `text` is a `std::string` type! Your code is also then not vulnerable to overrunning your `char` buffer.

Comment: @gsamaras: I'm currently changing some code that uses Boost Spirit. Lots of free time during compiles!

Comment: @gsamaras - One should know better than to try and give a spot on answer faster than Bathsheba :P

Comment: There is no specific requirement that the streaming operator that accepts a `const char *` calls the overload that accepts a `char`.  That is only one possible implementation choice.

Answer (score 3):

To print the address of an array element, you could do:

```
cout << " " << (void*)&text[i];
```

---

This:

```
cout << " " << &text[i];
```

is equivalent to this:

```
cout << " " << text + i;
```

which means that you ask to print the string, starting from index `i`.